# How to parse arbitrary tokens in Rust's procedural macros?

Tags: parsing, rust, macros, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently developing a parser for a DSL in Rust. I am using `syn`, `quote` and `proc-macro2` to help with that.

What causes problems for me is, that there are certain literal types in that DSL that I cannot parse. One example are single-quoted strings:

My TDD setup includes the following unit test:

```rust
#[test]
fn single_quoted_str() {
  let input: proc_macro2::TokenStream = quote!('single quoted');
  let literal = syn::parse2::<MySingleQuotedStringType>();
  assert!(literal.is_ok());
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, already the first line is failing with a `LexError`. I also tried using `TokenStream::from_str(...)` and `syn::parse_str(...)` – both resulting in the same issue.

How can I accept and parse completely arbitrary tokens in a macro? Using double quotes instead is not really an option since the DSL already exists. Also, there are other literal types for which the same would apply: For example, there is a date literal which follows the pattern `date'2023-02-26'`.

**Is there any general solution for that? I would only need a string token which is extracted using whitespace splitting. The rest I could implement manually.**

Comment: Procedural macros are not the right tool for developing a DSL that is **not** a subset of Rust's syntax. The crates you are trying to use work only with valid Rust code as input. Rust does not have single quoted strings as single quotes are used for character literals only. If you want to write your own DSL, I can recommend having a look at parser generators and lexers for Rust, like [lalrpop](https://github.com/lalrpop/lalrpop) or [logos](https://github.com/maciejhirsz/logos) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot do this. The input of proc macros is a token stream where each token has to be a valid token in the Rust lexicographical grammar. That grammar does not include single quoted string literals (single quote = single character literal).

Some things can work, like `date"2023-02-26"` which is just an identifier and then a string literal. But again, you cannot have any tokens that don't exist in Rust.

If you really *must* parse the exact DSL you are describing: pass a single string literal to your proc macro that contains the DSL. For example:

```
my_macro!("
    'some string'
    date'2023-02-26'
");
```

Then you just have the raw string inside your macro and can do whatever.